# Axes output not assigned

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axes

I'm working on an assignment in which we create a function that creates a blank figure. I think I have most of the function correct, but I also know that parts of it aren't. It is a very simple function, but I'm not sure exactly how to use the outputs. Below are the function and the code calling that function.

```
function [ax, f] = create_axes(fignum)

    figure(fignum)
    clf(fignum, 'reset')
    
    ax = axes('Parent',fignum)   
    axis(ax,'equal')
    box(ax,'on')
    
end
```

Code to call the above function:

```
fignum = 317;
[ax,f] = create_axes(fignum)
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `f` in your function. I presume you want to assign `f = figure(fignum)`?

Comment: Yes, you are exactly correct! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Once you have `ax` and `f`, you can use `f` anywhere you want to refer to the figure (for example, if you want to [`savefig(f, ...)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html#d122e1164926), or `ax` if you want to refer to the axes, like [`xlim(ax, ...)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html#d122e1475074)